# How to achieve the auto-shrink SwiftUI Navigation Title with UIKit?

Tags: swift, swiftui, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uinavigationbar

I am trying to achieve the auto-shrink large nav title like the Navigation Title in SwiftUI, but no matter what my nav title always stay shrinked and never appear in large title mode. How do i fix this? (code below)
[image]

```
func setup() {
    
    table.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    table.dataSource = self
    table.delegate = self
    table.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "mycell")
    table.separatorColor = .white
    table.backgroundColor = .black
    
    let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
    appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
    appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    
    navigationItem.title = "Todo List"
    navigationItem.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    navigationItem.standardAppearance = appearance
    
    view.addSubview(table)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as providing a configuration for large titles, you need to instruct your `navigationController` to use large titles

```
navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

The default configuration for a view controller should be to automatically use large titles if that is the preferred choice.  However you can set it explicitly per view controller:

```
navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always // or .automatic or .never
```

If the nav controller has `prefersLargeTitle = false` then large titles will never be displayed whatever the `largeTitleDisplayMode` setting.

Comment: you should change your profile to "GOAT"